# Bpy area_options usage

Tags: python, scripting

Anyone knows the purpose of bpy.ops.screen.area_options(). There is not much available in Blender documentations

Comment: Hello ! Here's link to what happens in the source code. I asume it's used to store some information about the mouse cursor and the screens right before a merge / split operation ?

Comment: @Gorgious, please share the link.

Comment: hehe sorry https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/d2aebf10fae7bd6f0e854deea2c3c776bd5cde8c/source/blender/editors/screen/screen_ops.c#L3598

Comment: @Gorgious. Thats ok. :) And thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Motivated by @Gorgious comment, i had a look at the code
[screen_ops.c](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/d2aebf10fae7bd6f0e854deea2c3c776bd5cde8c/source/blender/editors/screen/screen_ops.c#L3598)

It appears to be responsible for populating the options when we click on the border
[image]